# PHP mod rewrite can't work correctly

Tags: mod-rewrite

Here my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) image.php?names[]=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/([0-9a-zA-Z]+),([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) image.php?names[]=%1&names[]=%2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/([0-9a-zA-Z]+),([0-9a-zA-Z]+),([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) image.php?names[]=%1&names[]=%2&names[]=%3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/gallery/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) gallery.php?id[]=%1 [L]
```

this 2 strings doesn't work correctly

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/gallery/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) gallery.php?id[]=%1 [L]
```

When I go to gallery/hgJ56 , I see the content of first 2 strings

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) image.php?names[]=%1 [L]
```

I'm in trouble, can't understand^, please help! What can I do ?

Comment: Please explain what you want to do => what the user types, how it is modified internally by the server. There's room for improvement in your rewriterules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ [NC]

will match a string that ends with a `/` followed by an alphanumeric string, so it will match `gallery/hgJ56`, because it ends with `/hgJF6`.

If the rule is only supposed to match a string that begins with a `/` followed by an alphanumeric string, then you can change this rule to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ [NC]
```

and it will not longer match `gallery/hgJ56` and your other rule will work.

Note that you do not need to escape the `/` character i.e. `\/` and just `/` are equivalent.

You may also want to apply the `^` to the rest of your rules in case they also are only supposed to match the start of the string i.e  change

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/gallery/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ [NC]
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/gallery/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ [NC]
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please explain.

Comment: Ok, I've got it! Now, it works! But!!! When I go to gallery/hgJ56 the variable id doesn't exist!!!!

Comment: Here, the id variable, but actualy there is no id variable in galery.php!! RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/gallery/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /gallery.php?id=$1 [L]

Comment: @Anton the last rule needs a `%1` not a `$1` i.e. `RewriteRule ^(.*) /gallery.php?id=%1 [L] `

Comment: no, I tried! I changed to %1, it doesn't solve my problem!

Comment: @Anton if you can turn on the RewriteLog (see answer below for details). If not, temporarily change the last rule to add an `R` i.e. `RewriteRule ^(.*) /gallery.php?id=%1 [L,R]` and tell me what the result in your browser is. You can also directly access the `gallery.php?id=hgJ56` to see if works.

Comment: Yeah, directly access to gallery.php?id=hgJ56 works...

Comment: @Anton Temporarily change the last rule to add an R i.e. RewriteRule ^(.*) /gallery.php?id=%1 [L,R] and tell me what the result in your browser is

Comment: I did it! Nothing has changed!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a "cleaner" version of your rewriterules.

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ image.php?names[]=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/([0-9a-zA-Z]+),([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ image.php?names[]=$1&names[]=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/([0-9a-zA-Z]+),([0-9a-zA-Z]+),([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ image.php?names[]=$1&names[]=$2&names[]=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/gallery/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ gallery.php?id[]=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Tell me if they work.

And if that's not enough:

### Two hints:

If you're **not** in a hosted environment (= if it's *your own server* and *you **can** modify the virtual hosts*, not only the `.htaccess` files), try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)